# Difference between SDO_INSIDE and SDO_CONTAINS

Tags: oracle, spatial-query, oracle-spatial

I have this confusion between `SDO_INSIDE` and `SDO_CONTAINS`, Isn't it like both these queries need to return same result?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please head over to [The Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and give the articles there a good read. There is no need for begging at the end of your question. Instead, focus on writing a well thought out, researched question.  High quality questions are much more likely to get attention. If someone answers your question, lease make sure you accept their answer using the check box below the voting buttons. By the way, this was really more of a GIS question. Make sure you sign up for http://gis.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: *please (I hate typos.)

Answer (score 5):

You need to understand the 9-intersection model. Oracle's documentation on it in particular is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10826/sdo_intro.htm#i880253).

The difference between the two is the *order of parameters*. If geometry A **contains** geometry B, then geometry B **is inside** geometry A. So

```
SDO_CONTAINS(A, B) = SDO_INSIDE(B, A)
```